# $\left( 1 - |\alpha| \right)^{2} \leq |1 - 2\alpha\cos(x) + \alpha^{2}| \leq \left( 1 + |\alpha| \right)^{2}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{D}_{1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I'm trying to prove the following identity:

\begin{equation}
\left( 1 - |\alpha| \right)^{2} \leq |1 - 2\alpha\cos(x) + \alpha^{2}| \leq \left( 1 + |\alpha| \right)^{2} \;\; \forall x \in (0, \pi),
\end{equation}
where $ \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$, with $|\alpha| < 1$. When I work in $\mathbb{C}$, the inequality is true. But in $\mathbb{C}$, I can't prove the identity. I graphed the function $f(x) = |1 - 2\alpha\cos(x) + \alpha^{2}|$, and the identity seems to be true.

Comment: The upper bound is clear: $$
\left| {1 - 2\alpha \cos x + \alpha ^2 } \right| \le 1 + 2\left| \alpha  \right|\left| {\cos x} \right| + \left| \alpha  \right|^2  \le 1 + 2\left| \alpha  \right| + \left| \alpha  \right|^2  = (1 + \left| \alpha  \right|)^2. 
$$

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but for me the problem is the lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

Gary's comment resolves the upper bound. For the lower bound, the idea is similar to Mittens'; you can use Euler's formula for $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$ to write
$$
\left|1 - 2\alpha \cos x + \alpha^2 \right| = \left| (e^{ix} - \alpha)(e^{-ix} - \alpha)\right|
$$
and now apply the reverse triangle inequality (lower bound in Mittens' answer) to each factor to get
$$
\left| (e^{ix} - \alpha)\right| \left|(e^{-ix} - \alpha)\right| \geq |1 - |\alpha||^2 = (1 - |\alpha|)^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha\neq0$, express $\alpha$ in polar coordinates using Euler's formula, i.e., $\alpha=|\alpha|e^{i\theta}=|\alpha|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. The triangle inequality yields
$$\big|1-|\alpha|\big|\leq|1-\alpha|\leq1+|\alpha|$$
Observe that
$|1-\alpha|^2=1-2|\alpha|\cos\theta+|\alpha|^2$

Comment: This seems to work if $x=\arg \alpha$.